# How can I run a C++ .exe file from IntelliJ IDEA in Java and avoid an 'abort' exception?

Tags: java, c++, exception, intellij-idea, abort

I have a problem with combining C++ (VS 2019) and Java (IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3). I wrote a code in C++ and .exe file [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ilIy.png). But when I try to open it from IntelliJ IDEA, I get an [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exwOI.jpg)

C++:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
#include <complex> 
#include <list>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace complex_literals;

int main() {

    try {
        ifstream fin("toCPP.txt");
        int Nhn, fd, len;
        fin >> Nhn;
        string* hhn = new string[Nhn];
        for (int i = 0; i < Nhn; ++i) {
            fin >> hhn[i];
        }
        fin >> fd;
        fin >> len;
        fin.close();

        cout << "Nhn = " << Nhn << endl;
        cout << "hhn = ";
        for (int i = 0; i < Nhn; ++i) {
            cout << hhn[i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "fd = " << fd << endl;
        cout << "len = " << len << endl << endl;

        auto j = 1.i;
        double Td = pow(fd, -1);
        double* Hhn = new double[len];
        auto tmp = 0. + 0.i;

        ofstream fout("result.txt");
        for (int f = 0; f < len; f++) {
            Hhn[f] = 0;
            tmp = 0. + 0.i;
            for (int k = 0; k < Nhn - 1; k++) {
                tmp += strtod((hhn[k]).c_str(), 0) * exp(-j * (2 * M_PI * k * Td * f));
            }
            Hhn[f] = abs(tmp);
            if (f + 1 < len) fout << Hhn[f] << ", ";
            else fout << Hhn[f];
            cout << endl << "Hhn[" << f << "] = " << Hhn[f] << endl;
        }
        fout << endl << len;
        fout.close();
    }
    catch (double e) {
        cout << "error";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Java:

```
package com.maxwonderf;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class checkingCPP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File firstAppPath = new File("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\IdeaProjects\\sudoku\\result\\Debug\\result.exe");
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
                desktop.open(firstAppPath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. the file 'toCPP.txt' exists.

I tried to move .exe file, to use Debug and Release (strange things happened) configs.

Comment: One of those buttons in the crash dialog probably lets you inspect the crash in the debugger so you can gather information. Take advantage of the opportunity. If it doesn't make the offer, use the debugger anyway.

Comment: Side note: I see two `new`s and no `delete`s. Probably not all that important here, but not freeing resources when your done with them is a lousy habit to get into. Side note to side note: `new` is the tool you should reach for after you've exhausted everything but `malloc`. `std::vector` looks like a good fit for this use case.

Comment: The toCPP.txt file may well exist, but does it exist in the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)?

Comment: My guess is that the file fails to open (probably because of current working directory issues). **Always** check that files open successfully, there's too many ways that this can fail.

Comment: Also always check every IO transaction to ensure it succeeded. Even something as simple as `fin >> Nhn;` can fail for many reasons, and if it does, `Nhn` is either 0, not a good size for an array, or undefined, which may turn out to be a good size for the array but there's no way to know.

Comment: string* hhn = new string[Nhn]; no don't do this try to [avoid raw new/delete](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete). Use std::vector<std::string> if you want a resizable array of strings. Also do NOT use using namespace std;. Also try to avoid raw loops if you can, The readloop can then be a range based for loop like this std::vector<std::string> inputs(len); for(auto& input : inputs) fin >> input;

Comment: thank you guys, you helped me a lot.
I dont work with C++, but there isn`t complex number in Java, so I have to use this language.

Comment: @Max there is no builtin Complex type built-in in Java but you can find a library that implement it. That will be way more simple to use than trying to integrate with a different language this way.

Comment: Why not try `ProcessBuilder`? I would (since it looks like a console program) use it to execute `cmd.exe /c start result.exe` (with full path)